# Select value from a table where value equals value in query results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL.

Table A

```
WO_Number   Item_Number  QtyReq
J000001     T12345ZA        5
J000002     T54321ZA        4
J000003     T98765ZA        2
```

Table B

```
WO_Number   WC_Code    Qty
J000001        a       5
J000001        b       4
J000001        c       6
J000002        a       3
J000002        b       1
J000002        c       4
J000003        a       7
J000003        b       6
J000003        c       9
```

I am creating a view containing these two tables and what I need to achieve is select Qty from Table B where TableB.WC_Code equals 'a'.

I joined Table A and Table B on WO_Number.

I have seen similar questions asked, but not sure if the requirement is exactly the same and I don't entirely understand the syntax.

The resulting view should look like this:

```
WO_Number   Item_Number  QtyReq  Qtya
J000001     T12345ZA        5      5
J000002     T54321ZA        4      3
J000003     T98765ZA        2      7
```

The above tables are simplified. Below is the actual query:

```
SELECT     RIGHT(dbo.tJCHeader.JCno, LEN(dbo.tJCHeader.JCno) - 1) AS 'WO NUMBER', dbo.tJCHeader.DATEfinish AS 'Date of Closure', dbo.tSalesOrderLink.SOno AS 'Sales Order', 
                  dbo.tJCHeader.FGCode AS 'Item Number', dbo.tBOMh.UDtxt1 AS 'Film Grade', dbo.tJCHeader.QTYstd AS 'Qty To produce', dbo.tJCHeader.QTYact AS 'Good Qty Done', '' AS 'Error Qty Done',
                      (SELECT     RIGHT(RTRIM(dbo.tJCHeader.BOMCode), 6) AS Expr1) AS Machine, dbo.tBOMh.UDval1 AS 'Roll Width', dbo.tBOMh.UDval2 AS 'Roll Length', '' AS 'sq metres', '' AS 'Core Cut time', 
                  '' AS 'Core Cut quantity', '' AS 'Core Nothch time', '' AS 'Core Notch quantity', '0.317' AS 'Th Setup time', '' AS 'Th Slit time', '' AS 'Th Packing time', '' AS 'Rolls Scrapped quantity', 
                  '' AS 'Rolls Scrapped sqm', '' AS 'Overruns quantity', '' AS 'Overuns sqm', dbo.tSalesOrderLink.CustomerDesc AS 'Client', '' AS 'Operator', dbo.tJCLines.Qty1, dbo.tJCLines.WCCode
FROM         dbo.tBOMh INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tJCHeader ON dbo.tBOMh.BomCode = dbo.tJCHeader.BOMCode INNER JOIN
                  dbo.tJCLines ON dbo.tJCHeader.Indx = dbo.tJCLines.Indx LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.tSalesOrderLink ON dbo.tJCHeader.JCno = dbo.tSalesOrderLink.JCno
```

The field I need added to the view is dbo.tJCLines.Qty1 but only if dbo.tJCLines.WCCode = 'SLIT_DEC120' or 'SLIT_DEC056'.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will edit the question. I was trying to simplify it a bit.

Comment: I have added the actual query I am writing to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not all clear, but you might be looking for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.WO_Number=b.WO_Number
WHERE b.WC_Code='a'
```

According to your comment I assume you need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA AS a
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON a.WO_Number=b.WO_Number
                      AND b.WC_Code='a'
```

Comment: If there is not a record with "a" in TableB, data from TableA will not be displayed in case we use this criteria in WHERE clause

Comment: OK, I just thoufht the requirement is simply bringing related Qty data from TableB into TableA

Comment: The requirement is simply to bring Qty into table A where WCCode in table B equals 'a'

Comment: @StevenNel In this case replace the `WHERE` with `AND`

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to the join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON A.WO_Number = B.WO_Number AND B.WC_Code = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following SQL Select statement

```
select
    TableA.WO_Number,
    TableA.Item_Number,
    TableA.QtyReq,
    TableB.Qty
from TableA
left join TableB
    on TableA.WO_Number = TableB.WO_Number
    and TableB.WC_Code = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you only need Qty from TableB

```
select  Qty
    from TableB
    inner join TableA
    where TableA.WO_Number = TableB.WO_Number AND TableB.WC_Code = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work for you

`SELECT
  Qty
FROM
  TableB
  INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.WO_Code = TableA.WO_Code
WHERE
  TableB.WC_Code = 'a'`